# HTML key combination shortcut

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently trying to implement **shortcuts feature** on the menu of my web based project. I had already implemented single or double shortcut key combination (like **<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>** etc..,).

```
$("#MyField").keydown(function (eventData) {
     if (eventData.keyCode == 112) {
           eventData.preventDefault();
           myFunction_ToCall();
     }

});
```

But now I'm moving towards the combination of 3-keys, to access a `sub-subMenu`, because my menu is look like this:

1. Menu1

   1. SubMenu1

      1. **Sub-SubMenu1**
      2. **Sub-Sub-Menu2**
   2. SubMenu2
   3. SubMenue3
2. Menu2
3. Menu3
4. Menu4

So, to access the **`1. Sub-SubMenu1`** the path will be like `1. Menu1 > 1. SubMenu1 > 1. Sub-SubMenu1`, the **key combination will be like <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>`**.

I searched a lot, but couldn't find any better solution. And now I'm confused how to achieve it. Anyone can help me!!

Answer (score 2):

I would use `KeyboardEvent.key`, `KeyboardEvent.ctrlKey` and a tree where each sequence of keystrokes forms a branch :

```js
step = shortcuts = {
  "1": {
    "1": sayHello,
    "2": sayGoodbye
  }
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", function (ev) {
  if (ev.key === "Control") {
    step = shortcuts; // go back to the root
    ev.preventDefault();
  }
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", function (ev) {
  if (ev.ctrlKey && step[ev.key]) {
    step = step[ev.key]; // a node was reached
    if (typeof step === "function") {
      step(); // a leaf was reached
    }
  }
});

function sayHello () {
  console.log("Hello :-)");
}

function sayGoodbye () {
  console.log("Goodbye :-(");
}
```

```html
<p>Click here before trying shortcuts.</p>
```

Here is an improved version of the previous snippet :

```js
step = shortcuts = {
  "1": {
    "1": "sayHello",
    "2": "sayGoodbye"
  }
};

commands = {
  "sayHello": function () {
    console.log("Hello :-)");
  },
  "sayGoodbye": function () {
    console.log("Goodbye :-(");
  }
};

printShortcuts(shortcuts, "CTRL");

document.addEventListener("keydown", function (ev) {
  if (ev.key === "Control") {
    step = shortcuts; // go back to the root
    ev.preventDefault();
  }
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", function (ev) {
  if (ev.ctrlKey && step[ev.key]) {
    step = step[ev.key]; // a node was reached
    if (commands[step]) {
      commands[step](); // a leaf was reached
    }
  }
});

function printShortcuts (node, prefix) {
  if (typeof node === "string") {
    document.body.innerHTML += prefix + " : " + node + "()<br>";
  } else {
    for (var child in node) {
      printShortcuts(node[child], prefix + "-" + child);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Click here before trying shortcuts.</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your better solution. I'll soon implement it and give you my thankful feedback. :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about this example from [Keyboard events with Ctrl, Alt, Shift keys](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/keyboard_ctrl_alt_shift.htm)

**Take a look at how it captures combinations..**

```
function handleKeyDown(e) {
 var ctrlPressed=0;
 var altPressed=0;
 var shiftPressed=0;

 var evt = (e==null ? event:e);

 shiftPressed=evt.shiftKey;
 altPressed  =evt.altKey;
 ctrlPressed =evt.ctrlKey;
 self.status=""
    +  "shiftKey="+shiftPressed 
    +", altKey="  +altPressed 
    +", ctrlKey=" +ctrlPressed 

 if ((shiftPressed || altPressed || ctrlPressed)
     && (evt.keyCode<16 || evt.keyCode>18)) 
   alert ("You pressed the "+fromKeyCode(evt.keyCode)
    +" key (keyCode "+evt.keyCode+")\n"
    +"together with the following keys:\n"
    + (shiftPressed ? "Shift ":"")
    + (altPressed   ? "Alt "  :"")
    + (ctrlPressed  ? "Ctrl " :"")
   )
 return true;
}

document.onkeydown = handleKeyDown;
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but how can i use it in my solution !!